# Replace() : Needing to replace multiple character type from the same variable

Tags: email, ampscript

I've created a template and modules for multiple email automation. I'm having issues removing/replacing certain characters. I've used the replace() to swap out the empty spaces with the _. Now I need to do the same with the "!"

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [Replace AmpScript](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/string/Replace.html) function.

```
%%[
SET @String = "Amp Script!"
SET @String = Replace(@String,' ','_')
SET @String = Replace(@String,'!','_')
]%%

%%=v(@String)=%%
```

**Output:** Amp_Script_

Also, you can use [ReplaceList AmpScript](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/string/ReplaceList.html) function if you want to replace one or more string value with another string.

```
%%=ReplaceList('Amp Script!', '_', ' ', '!')=%%
```

**Output:** Amp_Script_